# Hide nav when clicking on anchor tags (Vanilla JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, nav, dom-events

I have a nav which is displayed on small screens. My goal is to hide that nav each time the anchor tags in it are clicked. 
I've tried multiple options until now, but none of them seem to work. I think the real problem here is that I don't know how to select all the anchor tags in the menu.  The solution that I'm looking has to be pure JS. Thank you in advance.

```
<nav id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
               <a href="#about">About</a>
               <a href="#services" onclick="closeNav();">Services</a>
               <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</nav>



.sidenav {
          width: 0;
         }
.sidenav.mobile-only {
         width:250px;
                     }

function closeNav() {
   myNav.classList.remove("mobile-only");
 }
```

Option 1

```
 var anchorTags = document.querySelectorAll('a')
 anchorTags.addEventListener('click', closeNav(), false);
 ** Uncaught TypeError: anchorTags.addEventListener is not a function
```

Option 2

```
 var anchorTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a")
 anchorTags.addEventListener('click', closeNav());
 **Uncaught TypeError: anchorTags.addEventListener is not a function
```

Option 3

```
 var anchorTags = document.querySelector("mobile-only a");
    for (var x = 0; x < anchorTags.length; x++) {
        anchorTags[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
            closeNav();
    });
    };

    **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

The only solution that I've found was to add the function inline, but I'm sure there has to be a better solution.

```
<a href="#about" onclick="closeNav();">About</a>
<a href="#services" onclick="closeNav();">Services</a>
<a href="#contact" onclick="closeNav();">Portofolio</a>
```

Later edit:
Option 4: The winner (there are better solutions than this which are listed bellow. Thanks everyone)

```
var anchorTags = document.getElementById("mySidenav").childNodes;
for (var x = 0; x < anchorTags.length; x++) {
    anchorTags[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
        closeNav();
});
};
```

Thank you everyone for your responses, I finally understood what the problem was. I've tried all your solutions and they work perfectly.

Comment: In Option 1 & 2 `anchorTags` contains all links, and you need to use the loop from Option 3 to add the event listeners. In Option 3 you only have a single element, hence there's no `.length` attribute. It's pretty amazing that you tried 3 versions and managed to use precisely the wrong approach in each case.

Comment: *document.querySelector* returns a single element (which implements the [*HTMLElement* interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)), you can't loop over that (unless it's select element or similar). *document.querySelectorAll* returns a [*NodeList*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not a single element, so you can't call *addEventListener* on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're going to go with Option 3 since it is closet to the solution.

You should be using `document.querySelectorAll('nav a')` or even better `document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav a')`. This will get you a node list of all elements that matched our selector. After that we can use `forEach` to loop over each node and bind our click event.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav a').forEach(function(a) {
    a.addEventListener('click', closeNav);
});
```

Note that I used `closeNav` instead of `closeNav()` - the `()` are important! Using `()` will try to invoke the function immediately rather than assigning the function as the handler for the event.

Answer (score 0):

In option 1, what returns after running `querySelectorAll`, is a [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which is similar to an array. You can't add an event listener to the list itself, you'll need to add the listener to each item in the list similar to what you've attempted to do in option 3. In option 2, it is the same problem, but this time with an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). In option 3, you've done `querySelector` rather than `querySelectorAll` which only returns the first element that matches the selector. so if you try option 3 with `querySelectorAll`, it should work.

Comment: Hey, thank you! I've tried this and it works. var anchorTags = document.getElementById("mySidenav").childNodes;
for (var x = 0; x < anchorTags.length; x++) {
    anchorTags[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
        closeNav();
});
};

Answer (score 0):

When you use `getElementsByTagName` what it returns is a Node collection, not a HTMLElement, therefore you need to loop it to add to each element the event listener

```
var anchorTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
[...anchorTags].map(elem => elem.addEventListener('click', closeNav));
```

Same thing with `querySelector`, it returns a HTMLElement (only one) and if you want them all use `querySelectorAll`, you need to pass it a CSS Selector

```
var anchorTags = document.querySelector("a.mobile-only");
[...anchorTags].map(elem => elem.addEventListener('click', closeNav));
```

I used array spread `[...arraish_element]` to give to the Node Collection all the methods of a true array and being able to use map there, or you can just use a for with the length of the nodecollection

Comment: You need `elem.addEventListener('click', closeNav)`